# How to properly display records using a linking table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having trouble displaying database records in the manner I want using PHP and Mysql.

I have 3 tables, `BOOKS`, `AUTHORS`, `BOOKS_AUTHORS`.

The `BOOKS` table has the following columns, `book_id`, `title`, `publish_date`, `thumbnail`. The `AUTHORS` table has the following columns, `author_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`. The `BOOKS_AUTHORS` table has the following columns, `books_authors_id`, `book_id` (linked to `book_id` in the `BOOKS` table), and `author_id` (linked to `author_id` in the `AUTHORS` table).

Here's the SQL I'm using to display the results.

```
SELECT books.book_id, title, publish_date, thumbnail, authors.author_id, first_name, last_name, books_authors.book_id, books_authors.author_id
FROM books, authors, books_authors
WHERE books.book_id = books_authors.book_id 
AND authors.author_id = books_authors.author_id 
AND books.book_id = (INSERT NUMBER HERE)
```

Everything works fine unless a book has more than 1 author. Let's say a book has 2 authors. I will get back 2 records that have the same title, publish_date, and thumbnail but each will have a different authors' name. So now I have 2 duplicate titles, 2 duplicate publish_dates, and 2 duplicate titles.
This isn't how I want to display the records.
I want both author names to appear under 1 title, 1 publish_date, and 1 thumbnail.

Comment: I remember we did it this way back in the day. And then 1992 came along and we changed to joins. Come join us... And then see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grouping by the fields you don't want duplicated, then using GROUP_CONCAT on the author information to have each author listed in the same row:

```
SELECT books.book_id, title, publish_date, thumbnail,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(authors.author_id,' ', first_name,' ', last_name))
FROM books, authors, books_authors
WHERE books.book_id = books_authors.book_id 
AND authors.author_id = books_authors.author_id 
AND books.book_id = (INSERT NUMBER HERE)
GROUP BY books.book_id, title, publish_date, thumbnail
```

I would also use an inner join instead of listing your tables and then a where clause. This is typically easier to read. So the middle section would be:

```
FROM books
INNER JOIN books_authors ON books.book_id = books_authors.book_id 
INNER JOIN authors ON authors.author_id = books_authors.author_id 
WHERE books.book_id = (INSERT NUMBER HERE)
```

Comment: kkball thank you so much MUCH appreciated it worked perfectly!